# Quick way to test if all dictionary items are 'True'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hello in a program I am making I require the user to enter their shipping details, and once they have done this they can continue to confirm their order. However I do not want the user to prematurely skip past the shipping details form without filling out all of the fields. Here is the dictionary for storing their details:

```
user_details = {"Full Name": None, "Phone Number": None, "Street Address": None, "City": None, "Postcode": None}
```

Once they have a value for each key I want them to be able to continue but not before this. I am looking for a quick way to test if all values a true/ exist. Thanks!

Comment: `all(user_details.values())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all(user_details.values())
```

This will return true if all the values are not none, otherwise false

Comment: Not true.  If the value is `False`, it will not work.  If you want to check just for not being `None`, use `not any(detail is None for detail in user_details.values())`

Comment: @zondo or `all(detail is not None ...)`!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> user_details.values()
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> if None in user_details.values():
...   print "none in there"
... 
none in there
```

Comment: Actually the simplest solution, no need for all